# Can you help me translate this to ksh

Tags: bash, ksh, dotfiles

I use to put the following lines in my `bashrc` but I cannot use bash as a login shell anymore.
My login shell is now ksh. When I put this in my .profile file and source it I get an error from ksh.
How should I modify it such that it works ?

```
if [ "x$DISPLAY" == "x" ]                                                                        
then                                                                                             
    function tvim(){ tmux new-session "vim $@" ; }                                               
else                                                                                             
    function tvim(){ tmux -2 new-session "TERM=screen-256color vim $@" ; }                       
fi
```

---

.profile

```
loginshell=1
SH_LEVEL=0
export ENV=$HOME/.envfile
export PROFILE_SETTINGS_FILE="$PROFILE_SETTINGS_FILE:~/.profile"
```

---

`.envfile` : A lot of env variables definition I cannot show and bash on the last line

---

`.bashrc`

```
if [ "x$DISPLAY" == "x" ]                                                                        
then                                                                                             
    function tvim(){ tmux new-session "vim $@" ; }                                               
else                                                                                             
    function tvim(){ tmux -2 new-session "TERM=screen-256color vim $@" ; }                       
fi
```

---

I do not have a `.kshrc`

Comment: *I get an error from ksh*  are you going to tell us what the error is, or do we have to guess?  By the way, your syntax for a function is suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem 3 month age :)

I just added in your .profile :

```
bash
```

in your bashrc :

```
if [ "x$DISPLAY" == "x" ]                                                                        
then                                                                                             
    function tvim(){ tmux new-session "vim $@" ; }                                               
else                                                                                             
    function tvim(){ tmux -2 new-session "TERM=screen-256color vim $@" ; }                       
fi

loginshell=1
SH_LEVEL=0
export ENV=$HOME/.envfile
export PROFILE_SETTINGS_FILE="$PROFILE_SETTINGS_FILE:~/.profile"
```

Comment: In your .profile call bash and in your bashrc call your if ... :)

Comment: actually it does not work for me, but I am not sure why doing this it looks like I am loosing all environment variables... thanks for your answer, it is pbbly a pb particular to my setup

Comment: You need to have the bash at the first line of your .profile ! :)

Comment: not working, I really think this is a bad question. I vote to close it

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `.kshrc` file. Chances are, whatever you have in `.bashrc` will work, but you may need to change some parts if you use `bash`-specific features.

```
cp .bashrc .kshrc
```